# How do I convert mod_rewrite (QSA option) to Nginx equivalent?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm looking to convert the following `mod_rewrite` rule to the [Nginx equivalent](http://wiki.codemongers.com/NginxHttpRewriteModule):

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^foo/*$ /bar/index.php [L,QSA]
```

So far I have:

```
rewrite ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/index.php?title=$1&$query_string last;
rewrite ^foo/?$ /bar/index.php?$query_string break;
```

The problem is (I think!) that the query string doesn't get appended. I haven't found a way to port the `QSA` argument to Nginx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These rewrite rules made the scripts work:

```
rewrite ^/foo/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /bar/index.php?title=$1&$2;
rewrite ^/foo /bar/index.php;
```

Answer (score 19):

QSA is automatic in NGINX.

If you don't want it, add ? to the end of your new location

rewrite ^/foo /bar/index.php? last;

Comment: This is correct. The docs (at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html ) say:
"If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them."
(Note: "If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended")