# Mod Rewrite for NGINX

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm currently using nginx as a transparent proxy for apache.  I would like to use nginx + fcgi(php) but need mod-rewrite support.

Is this possible or is there an alternative solution to my woes?

This is for only 1 site, would litespeed be an effective solution?

Comment: Related question, (possible duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280488/how-do-i-convert-mod-rewrite-qsa-option-to-nginx-equivalent

Comment: Related question, with link to converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840497/convert-htaccess-to-nginx/11422788#11422788

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nginx has a rewrite module: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule

It doesn't support the same syntax as mod_rewrite, but has similar features.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I was hoping to get something for mod_rewrite.  I went ahead and checked out litespeed, so far that's working fine.