# convert htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having no luck converting htaccess rules to nginx rewrite. I've checked out the NginxRewriteModule documentation and have a few done, but the more complicate ones I'm at a loss for.  Here's what I'm looking at:

```
RewriteRule    ^$                                               /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
RewriteRule    ([0-9A-Za-z]{12})-del-([0-9A-Za-z]+)/.+$         /cgi-bin/index.cgi?del=$1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\.html?|$)$                   /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)               /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$   /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&usr_login=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)        /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&usr_login=$1&id=$2&fname=$3 [L]

#RewriteRule    ^Reseller\.html$                                         /cgi-bin/Templates/Pages/english/Reseller.html [L]
RewriteRule    ^checkfiles\.html$                                       /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=checkfiles [L]
RewriteRule    ^contact\.html$                                          /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=contact [L]
RewriteRule    ^premium\.html$                                          /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=payments [L]
RewriteRule    ^login\.html$                                            /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=login [L]
RewriteRule    ^catalogue(.*)\.html$                                    /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=catalogue&date=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^news([0-9]*)\.html$                                     /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=news&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^n([0-9]+)-.*\.html$                                     /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=news_details&news_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^free([0-9]+)\.html$                     /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=registration&aff_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^users/([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})/?([0-9]+|$)        /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=user_public&usr_login=$1&fld_id=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule    ^embedmp3-([0-9A-Za-z]{12})\.html$   /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=mp3_embed&file_code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^embedmp4-([0-9A-Za-z]{12})\.html$   /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=mp32_embed&file_code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^box$                                    /cgi-bin/index_box.cgi [L]

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})(/[^\/]*/?|$)$            /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=user_public&usr_login=$1&fld=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+).html(.*)                        /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=$1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Better for http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 36):

Online tools to translate Apache .htaccess to Nginx rewrite tools include:

- http://winginx.com/htaccess
- http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Note that these tools will convert to equivalent [rewrite expressions](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule) using `if` statements, but they should be converted to `try_files`. See:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files

Comment: this one didnt seem to be working for me but this did: http://winginx.com/htaccess

Comment: Neither did work for me. I tried a very basic rewrite rule.

Comment: can you tell me, where  should I use of the output ? in the php file ? I used of [this](http://winginx.com/htaccess), and it gave me a output contained `if`, Now I want to know how should I use it ?

Answer (score 10):

Have not tested it yet, but the looks are better than [the one](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) Alex mentions.

The description at [winginx.com/en/htaccess](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) says:

> **About the [htaccess to nginx converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess)**
>
> The service is to convert an Apache's .htaccess to nginx configuration instructions.
>
> First of all, the service was thought as a mod_rewrite to nginx converter. However, it allows you to convert some other instructions that have reason to be ported from Apache to nginx.
>
> Note server instructions (e.g. php_value, etc.) are ignored.
>
> The converter does not check syntax, including regular expressions and logic errors.
>
> Please, check the result manually before use.

Comment: winginx.com/htaccess not work

Comment: Just noticed yesterday that it is down right now, yes. Hopefully it will come back online.

Answer (score 9):

Rewrite rules are pretty much written the same way with nginx:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Which rules are causing you trouble? I could help you translate those!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make a Php script to parse your old htaccess, I am using this one for PRestashop rules :

```
$content = $_POST['content'];

    $lines   = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    $results = '';

    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $items = explode(' ', $line);

        $q = str_replace("^", "^/", $items[1]);

        if (substr($q, strlen($q) - 1) !== '$') $q .= '$';

        $buffer = 'rewrite "'.$q.'" "'.$items[2].'" last;';

        $results .= $buffer.PHP_EOL;
    }

    die($results);
```

Comment: It's a shame a halfway decent answer was harmed by a flippant comment. I've edited it out.

Comment: This answer may be a lifesaver as a quick solution anyhow , but it's best not to rewrite like this. Especially for an e-commerce website. Please read this doc https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

Answer (score 2):

Use this:
http://winginx.com/htaccess

Online converter, nice way and time saver ;)

Comment: If you look closely, you can see that I posted that link way before you did..