# Convert to nginx rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, rule

Could someone help me to convert this rule for nginx?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: See my comment here for a converter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422788/189431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, try this:

```
location / {
   if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)/(.*)/ ) {
       rewrite ^ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2&$args last;
   }
}
```

Also please read [documentantion](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) about nginx-rewrite module

Comment: Thanks. But is "location / {" required? Or can i use the if statement within "server {"?

Comment: No, of course not. You could insert this into server section, or create named location. Please, read documentation, there are more info.

Comment: Hmm, i was just able to use/test it yesterday and it doesnt work. In the documentation of nginx, i can't find what i want. Is it still possible, that someone or Sergei can help me one more time? :(

Comment: Could you provide several examples of urls? And please attach you nginx.conf if possible