# Convert .htaccess to Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have rewrite .htaccess like that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

i try to convert in NGINX rewrite
but not success

```
# nginx configuration location / { rewrite ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 redirect; if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break; } }
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927184/converting-htaccess-to-nginx-mod-rewrite/14967560#14967560

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert htaccess to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840497/convert-htaccess-to-nginx)