# Nginx config for pretty URLs

Tags: php, nginx, url-routing

Previously I was working with Apache server (I had a special .htaccess) for my router, and everything worked as expected:

request: `test.local/index/action` was handled by `test.local/index.php`.

My .htaccess file was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**The problem:** Now, I need to implement same functionality in Nginx. I implement nginx configs for my websites including in main nginx.conf *-nginx folder- /include.d/test.conf* . I tried this *test.conf* configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  productlocator.local;
    root   /var/www/test/;
    index  index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
         # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
             return 404;
         }
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
         include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

Requests to `test.local/index.php` are properly handled, but requests like `test.local/index/action` result with `404 Not Found` error.

**The question:** How do I configure Nginx for my router to work?

Comment: Your server name is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert htaccess to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840497/convert-htaccess-to-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
server_name test.local;
```

instead

```
server_name  productlocator.local;
```

And then look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)