# How to do like apache QSA flag with nginx when you use try_files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to convert some apache rules into nginx ones, and im new to nginx ...

So I searched and searched; but didn't find what I want to do. Here is the lines I want to convert in Nginx :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And here is what I tried:

```
location ~ ^/(?<page>[^\/]+)$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php?page=$page;
}
location ~ ^/(?<page>[^\/]+)?(?<qsa>[.*]+)$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php?page=$page&$qsa;
}
```

This isn't doing the job. What am i doing wrong?

## EDIT

It was too long so i processed it with PHP, but i still wish an answer to this, **i will be generous** with anyone will answer nicely to this question !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280488/how-do-i-convert-mod-rewrite-qsa-option-to-nginx-equivalent ?

Comment: @Sumurai8 i seen it, but i can't mind how to make it works with try_files

Comment: I am sadly not that knowledgable in nginx, and don't really have a nginx server to test things out :-| I hope you get your answer ;-)

Comment: i hope too, thx :) (if you want to initiate yourself to nginx, you can make a dualboot under ubuntu, and `apt-get nginx` ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache **QSA** flag is query-string-append, in the Nginx world **the query string is stored in `$args`.**

So with try_files something like that should work:

```
location ~ ^/(?<page>[^\/]+)$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php?page=$page&$args;
}
```

Now I do not understand all the things you do in the location 'regex', (I'm a weak human, when I read regex I always feel like six year old kids trying to read their first words).

Using things like

```
location ~ ^/(.*) {
    try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?page=$1&$args;
}
```

Should already manage the directory test (the `$uri/` test check for the directory access), the real file direct access (`$uri`) and then fallback to index.php with the given url as page argument.

Your current first apache rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

It checks for *direct directory access* (`-d`), *direct file access* (`-f`), *symbolic links* (`-s`) or *direct file-with-size-greater-than-0 access* with `-s`, this last one is a subset of `-f` so i'm not sure you need it.

So the only thing we still have to handle is symbolic links direct access. This is managed by a configuration option in nginx

```
disable_symlinks off;
```

For the **NC** tag, case insensitive pattern comparison, it should not be a problem with something like `/*`, no character in the pattern.

Comment: Much thanks with this ! To explain the regex mmhhh, i would say that i'm parsing the URI from `/` to `/`, cuz i use it like that in my PHP script :)

Comment: Just edited it ! This was the good way but you forgot `&` between `$page` and `$args`

Comment: added your fix on the answer, better with the `&`, you were right.

Comment: It's more likely that people would want the explicit parameters to overwrite anything present in the query string, in which case they need to go after the `$args` parameter, like this: `/index.php?$args&page=$page`. Also be wary of using array-creating parameters like `tag[]=` that could also appear in `$args`, thus add to the array rather than overwrite it.