# NGINX is serving me php files instead of executing them

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I've found many people who had the same problem as me, however I couldn't find the right solution.

I'm running a NGINX server via vagrant and homestead. On the production end I'm using apache and therefore I have an htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^cms-system/public|^assets)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms-system/public/$1 [L]
```

I use this htaccess to rewrite all urls (except cms-system/public and assets) to my index.php which is in cms-system/public.

I've tried to convert this htaccess to a nginx config with this tool: https://winginx.com/en/htaccess Which did not work very well.. I've made some adjustments. The exception rules work, however I can't get the rewrite for the index.php to work. Could someone please help me?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name company.dev;
    root "/home/vagrant/company/";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ ^/cms-system/public/(.*) {

    }

    location ~ ^/assets/(.*) {

    }

    location / {
        if ($request_uri !~ "-f"){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /cms-system/public/$1 break;
        }
    }

# original location rule
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
#   }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/company.dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/company.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/company.dev.key;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure PHP7 is creating the `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` file? The default PHP-FPM pool must use that socket file.

Comment: Hi. Let me help you because answer is really horrible. Am I correct with following statements? 1) if we request `/images/logo.png` and `<root>/images/logo.png` not found, but `<root>/cms-system/public/images/logo.png` exists - need to send this file. 2) All not found requests (except /assets/*) served via `<root>/cms-system/public/index.php`. Also, 4) do you need support of direct requests like `/cms-system/public/index.php` or `/cms-system/public/images/logo.png`?. And 5) do you need requests like `/some.php/custom/path/`?

Answer (score 5):

This is all you need:

```
location / {
try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
if ($uri !~* "^/(cms-system\/public|assets)$") {set $block "A";}
if (!-e $request_filename) {set $block "${block}B";}
if ($block = "AB") {rewrite ^(.*)$ /cms-system/public/$1 last;}
}
```

instead of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^cms-system/public|^assets)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms-system/public/$1 [L]
```

This is recommended for security reasons:

```
location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
deny all;
}
```

Read also:
[porting-standard-apaches-mod_rewrite-rules-to-nginx](https://ma.ttias.be/porting-standard-apaches-mod_rewrite-rules-to-nginx/)
[How do I convert mod_rewrite (QSA option) to Nginx equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280488/how-do-i-convert-mod-rewrite-qsa-option-to-nginx-equivalent)

Comment: correction.. it doesn't work after all... caching got me fooled. I'm able to reach the assets and the valemus/public directory directly, however only through the full path instead of them both becoming top level directories. 

The base url is giving me a 403 and all other urls are resulting in a 500.

Comment: @MartijnImhoff Does nginx have access to those folders?